# geoJSON layer order leaflet

Tags: z-index, leaflet, layer, geojson

I have problem with geoJSON layer order in Leaflet. I have three polygon layers in leaflet, all geoJSON, all as overlay. But I'm not able to figure out, how to set layer order. I've tried autoZIndex: true/false - didn't work. Always after toggling layer visibility it are reordered and I'm really unhappy :(

Below is part of my code. I'm begginer, so I will be glad to any help.
Thanks,
Dan

```
var povoden_5q = L.geoJson(povoden_5q_diba, {style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature});  
var povoden_20q = L.geoJson(povoden_20q_diba, {style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
var povoden_100q = L.geoJson(povoden_100q_diba, {style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature});


map = new L.Map('mapa', {
    layers: [topo, povoden_5q]      
    });

var podklad = {
    "Letecký snímek": ortofoto,
    "Topografická mapa": topo
    }
var overlay = {
    "Záplavové území pětileté vody": povoden_5q,        
    "Záplavové území dvacetileté vody": povoden_20q,        
    "Záplavové území stoleté vody": povoden_100q        
    }


map.setView(new L.LatLng(50.9296561, 15.1377869),15);

L.control.layers(podklad, overlay,{collapsed:false, autoZIndex:true}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `layer.bringToFront()` and `layer.bringToBack()` methods?

In your case, something like:

```
...
L.control.layers(podklad, overlay,{collapsed:false, autoZIndex:true}).addTo(map);
povoden_5q.bringToBack();
povoden_100q.bringToFront();
```

or something like that.

See the [docs here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-bringtofront).

Comment: Hi, yes here it could help because I have only three layers, but what about four, five... layers? This will be functional only for less than three layers am I right? Dan

Comment: Haven't experimented with it myself, but I'd guess that calling `.bringToFront()` on, for example, four layers in succession will result in the last layer being on top, the second-to-last being directly underneath, the third-to-last being underneath the second-to-last, and the forth-to-last/first being at the bottom.  Yeah?

Comment: It's pretty easy to specify layer order when adding geojson layers directly to the map, rather than via the `L.control.layers()` controller.  I'm surprised there's no way to do the same with `L.control.layers()`, though nothing's mentioned in the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers).

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful, as it worked for me. Try this in your Code,
order can be rearranged, which layer you want first proceeding other layers:

```
var overlayMaps = {
"Province Layer":layer1,
"Districts Layer":layer2,
"Tehsil Layer":layer3
};

// Layer control
L.control.layers(overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```